# Elastic Cloud | Lens Double Bar Chart

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

i'm new to ElasticCloud, and i'm trying to see if it has all the needs for my data analysis.
I'm trying to create a simple bar chart, but i'm not being able to.
I've already uploaded the data and try several ways to achieve this but so far no luck.

This is what i'm trying to achieve [Bar Chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RkIoY.png)

Furthermore, i've also tryied Agregation Based and TSVB

Below is some test data

```
"1","3","211","1",NULL,"5","dummy data","dummy data","dummy data","email@email.com","dummy data","dummy data","1","0",NULL,"0","9.0",NULL,"5",NULL,"1","2019-10-01 08:41:33","2019-10-01 18:40:48",NULL

"2","3","141","0","8","1","dummy data","dummy data","dummy data","email@email.com","dummy data","dummy data","1","0",NULL,"0","5.0",NULL,"5",NULL,"1","2019-10-01 08:42:35","2019-10-01 10:21:46",NULL

"3","3","1001","1",NULL,"6","dummy data","dummy data","email@email.com","dummy data","dummy data","1","0","684","0","10.0",NULL,"5",NULL,"1","2019-10-01 08:46:58","2019-10-01 10:43:25",NULL
```

Can someone help me.

Regards

Comment: You'll need to tell us a bit more about your data...

Comment: Its a simple data...one id, 2 dates (created_at and updated_at), one other id that connects with other data(which for this test we dont use)..and some "text" fields

Comment: Please add some test data to reproduce your case. Put differently: help us help you!

Comment: Test data below:
"1","3","211","1",NULL,"5","dummy data","dummy data","dummy data","email@email.com","dummy data","dummy data","1","0",NULL,"0","9.0",NULL,"5",NULL,"1","2019-10-01 08:41:33","2019-10-01 18:40:48",NULL

"2","3","141","0","8","1","dummy data","dummy data","dummy data","email@email.com","dummy data","dummy data","1","0",NULL,"0","5.0",NULL,"5",NULL,"1","2019-10-01 08:42:35","2019-10-01 10:21:46",NULL

Comment: Thanks but please update your question, it's not legible in comments

Comment: thanks...i've placed the test data on the question itself

Comment: Put this simple: i need to aggregate the data by year and then by month...this will lead to 2 columns for each month - one for the current year and another for the last year. Maybe this kind of chart is outside what is normally done (dont know..i'm kind new to Elastic and the ecosystem arount Elastic)